# Search and replace through a multifile project in AUCTeX?

Tags: auctex, dired, search, regular-expressions

I am about to adopt Emacs to be the only editor I use in all what I am writing including LaTeX documents. I came from WYSIWYG editor which served that purpose fairly nice, namely TexStudio or TXS for short. For the transition from TXS to Emacs I am still missing the way TXS deals with executing massive regexp query search & replace with highlighting the matches and restriction of the search to only those project-related `.tex` files. I deeply miss that in Emacs now. See a screenshot of TXS below:

**TeXStudio Query in a Multifile LaTeX Project** 
[image]

I would like to emphasize the points in the workflow to be achieved in Emacs:

1. RegExp Query Search and Replacement only in the project-related `.tex` files.
2. Highlighting the matches
3. An overview of the highlighted results all together in a manageable layout (similar to the log view of `Magit` in Emacs when you press `l` followed by another `l` or simply like `C-x d` in Dired mode
4. How to know how much replacement or inspection matches done with or remaining and a way to *resume* query in case it is broken by a clumsy keystroke that stops the query
5. A clean way out of this messy query by closing and saving all related files and back to the state before invoking this query

I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/270930/1288722) but my intention is to be more like `CW` that anyone can share his best workflow to get this common job done. My current approach(es) as follows:

**First Workflow**

1. Dired mode `% g` will mark all files containing that regexp. Cons: this will include even file unrelated to the project including non .tex files.
2. `C-x 3` opens a new buffer while keeping an eye on the first buffer as my orientation overview of what marked files I have to query in the new buffer individually
3. Running the query by `C-c q`. It has very nice switches like `!` replace all without asking plus highlighting matches within the opened file. But this means I have to run the same query each time and for every marked file.
4. After doing all marked files I hit `C-x s !` to save all in one keystroke. Phew!

### [image]

**Second Workflow -- preferred**

- Marking all `.tex` files using `% m` within Dired-mode by regexp in order to mark only `.tex` files so basically running `\.tex` will get me there.
- `C-x 3` same as above to keep one buffer for overview and the other for query
- Executing `Q` within Dired which is query replace regexp in *marked* files only. Alternatively `A` is only regexp search query. A full-fledged query will be executed and a help menu by `?` is generously provided
- `C-x s !` save and close all the mess. Otherwise I had to close the opened files one by one which is tedious. I hope there is a way to close only those we bothered.

[image]

### How do I approximate TXS's regexp search/replace query in multifiles?

**Note**

- Emacs 24.4 on Windows 7

Comment: This question currently has a "close" vote for being too broad, which I'm inclined to agree with.  Could you please narrow the question down to a more discrete version (perhaps along the lines of "how do I approximate TeXStudio's regexp query search in multiple files")?  "What's your best workflow?" is very broad and is likely to yield lengthy and opinion-based answers.

Comment: I can't write a full answer right now, but you should look into wgrep.

Comment: @Malabarba, please consider upgrading your comment to an answer if you think this will satisfy the criteria mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to search for text patterns in your project, then you may want to use Projectile along with Helm.

- <kbd>M-x helm-projectile-grep</kbd>
- Type text pattern or regex pattern.
- See updated results for every character entered.

Here is a demo of `helm-projectile-grep`:

[image: helm-projectile-grep]

You can save into a separate buffer to refer later using `Save results in grep buffer` action` (you switch to action buffer using <kbd>TAB</kbd>, by default).

If you haven't heard of Helm, you can read [my Helm tutorial](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html). Visit my [Helm Projectile tutorial](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) for more demos and guidance on Helm Projectile.

Alternative, you can also use `rgrep`, which is built-in:

- <kbd>M-x rgrep</kbd>
- Enter text/regex pattern into `Search for:` prompt, i.e. "test"
- Enter file type to search for into `Search for "test" in file:`, i.e. `*.tex`.
- Enter directory to recursively search (hence the name `rgrep`).
- Press <kbd>RET</kbd> and see results.

A `rgrep` demo:

[image]

In regard to your criteria:

> 1. RegExp Query Search and Replacement only in the project-related `.tex` files.

Both Helm and `rgrep` support this feature.

> 2. Highlighting the matches

Same as above.

> 3. An overview of the highlighted results all together in a manageable layout

Same as above.

> 4. How to know how much replacement or inspection matches done with or remaining and a way to *resume* query in case it is broken by a clumsy keystroke that stops the query

If you want to replace matches, you can use [wgrep](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) to perform replacement to a `*Grep*` buffer. Once you finish and sync back the `*Grep*` buffer, everything will be replaced according to the text you replaced.

You "resume" by running the query again if you accidentally stop it. But using Helm, you have a `helm-resume` command that resume you back to previous on going operation if you accidentally cancel it.

> 5. A clean way out of this messy query by closing and saving all related files and back to the state before invoking this query

Actually, you don't have to kill any buffer if you use tools like [helm-mini](http://tuhdo.github.io/static/part3/helm-mini.gif). Managing thousands of open buffers is a breeze: you can narrow to your desire buffers with a short text pattern. You can kill all at once if you want.

Here is a demo of `helm-mini`:

[image: helm-mini]

See the detail explanation in [Helm Github page, in "Advanced Usage" section](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm#advanced-usage).

Comment: I think I have to try and study projectile with helm. Thanks for your screenshots-rich tutorials!

Comment: what packages I need to install to get these decent functions: `projectile`, `helm` and `helm-projectile` is obvious, what else? Plus there are two MELPA pkgs `helm-pojectile` and `helm projectile-all` any recommendations here?

Comment: That's enough already. Then, follow the configuration in my guides. You should check the `Installation` section in my Helm and Helm Projectile guides.

Comment: what keystrokes do you use in `rgrep` to visit the match occurrences (forward or backward) in the upper and lower buffer?

Comment: I used `M-g n` and `M-g p` when cursor is not in the `*Grep*` buffer. In `*Grep*` buffer, I simply use `n` and `p`. See [Compilation Mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation-Mode.html). You should have a look at Helm and Helm Projectile when you are free. It's definitely worth your time.

Comment: it was an Emacs-changing experience to meet helm and helm-projectile, Thanks! But, grep search not working. Can you pls care to look at this post: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7178/2443

Answer (score 5):

If I understood what you want, RefTeX' [`reftex-isearch-minor-mode`](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.html#IDX246) should be what you are after.  From its description in the manual:

> Toggle a minor mode which enables incremental search to work globally on the entire multifile document. Files will be searched in the sequence they appear in the document.

As [reported](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/6004/what-is-your-best-workflow-to-do-a-massive-query-in-a-multifile-project-in-aucte/6006#comment9146_6006) by T. Verron, this works with regexps as well.

To enable this minor mode in all *TeX buffer, add one of the following lines to your init file

```
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook (lambda () (reftex-isearch-minor-mode))) ; for AUCTeX
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook (lambda () (reftex-isearch-minor-mode))) ; for the Emacs' bultin TeX mode.
```

Comment: Good to know as I use reftex. But since no regexp is supported I doubt this approach would be any better!

Comment: Apparently, pressing `M-r` in the search buffer switches to regexp search, just like it does for regular `isearch`.

Comment: And the usual shortcut for regexp isearch (`C-M-s`) does work too.

Comment: @T.Verron thank you! Actually I haven't used this feature extensively, the last time I tried it regexp search didn't work, who knows what I tried then `;-)`

Comment: @T.Verron from the menu bar->ref->global actions->search version and replace version for whole document provides better regexp as you can edit your expression while in minibuffer but I don't know what function is this and what is the keybinding.

Comment: Yes, I have seen that, but it only searches for the first occurrence for what I understand.

Comment: @T.Verron it matches all project files you can try it out just hit `M-,` to go to the next occurance

Answer (score 3):

In case you are not aware, you can open **Dired** on only a particular set of files (located in any directories, anywhere). IOW, you can use Dired as your entry point for all of the files of a project.  The usual Dired features work in this context: operating on marked files, etc.

If you use library [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) then you can have Dired bookmarks that you use to give you different "views" of differents sets of files, their markings, etc.

(Emacs Wiki is down for maintenance currently, and for a few more days, so that link is temporarily inaccessible.)

Comment: Is it like Emacs narrowing `C-x n n`? can you please enrich your answer with more details. Thanks.

Comment: No; nothing to do with `C-x n n` - just a little known Dired feature. `C-h f dired` tells you that you can pass as argument a list of (e.g. absolute) file (and directory) names instead of a directory name. That's the key. Library [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/DiredPlus) makes it easier to use this interactively. (But again, the wiki is down temporarily, so that link too is not available at the moment.)