# Can't get grep search in helm-projectile working?

Tags: helm, microsoft-windows, projectile

I got thankfully introduced to use helm and helm-projectile for all the goodies it has and especially the `helm-projectile-grep-search`. I must say, this supercharged Emacs by a long shot. I learned that from this great tutorial : http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html.  Unfortunately, everyhting else was fine except grep search-related commands, they throwed this error by invoking them on my machine:

`Error during redisplay: (eval (helm-show-candidate-number (car-safe helm-mode-line-string))) signaled (wrong-type-argument integer-or-marker-p nil) [6 times]
Error running timer helm-projectile-grep-or-ack: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)`

The same error was issued when I used `C-s` or `C-u C-s` recursive grep search while in `helm-find-files` bound to `C-x C-f`. I run this on marked files with `C-SPC`.

But `rgrep` works well which is built in Emacs (see image below). So I don't know what am I missing to get grep search work.

[image]

**Notes**
Machine: Windows 7 32bit.
Emacs 24.4
Helm/Projectile/Helm-projectile all updated from MELPA.

I have installed Cygwin and added to Path:

[image]

Comment: `rgrep` used the built-in `grep` (written in Elisp) while `helm-projectile-grep` needs the external `grep`. If you don't like Cygwin, probably you should look at [Mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/), install it and set $PATH point to its binary directory.

Comment: @TuDo still not working I tried MingW and Cygwin32. I have my emacs in `c:\emacs` not in program files. I added to path `c:\cygwin\bin`. What am I missing?

Comment: how to know if my cygwin is installed properly and recognized by emacs? I run M-x projectile-grep and it returns: Grep exited abnormally with code 123. So meaning cygwin not in charge, right?

Comment: You put the directory at the beginning of Path variable, so cygwin binaries are alwaysbused first. Also to makw sure, in Emacs execute getenv command and type "PATH" (without double quotes) to verify the value.

Comment: @TuDo Now when I issue `M-x getenv RET PATH RET`, the `C:\cyqwin\bin` appears first, restart Emacs, I get the same error when doing grep search.

Comment: `exit grep with error code 2`?!

Comment: @TuDo is it possible that I have missed some libraries from Cygwin? I did the default install nothing too special.

Comment: Could you enter `grep --version` in `eshell` to see if your Emacs actually sees `grep` from Cygwin? The reason Helm uses external `grep` is for asynchronous processing. That is, your Emacs won't be blocked while grepping a large amount of text and live grep is only possible with async processing.

Comment: @TuDo `grep (GNU grep) 2.4.2`, so Cyqwin grep not picked up, what can I do next?

Comment: Does that command prints the same in Cygwin shell? I just want to make sure it's the same or different. If it's different then Emacs still cannot see. After next few hours I will get home and have my Windows machine to check the proper configuration.

Comment: @TuDo which packages are relevant to grep search in cygwin, that can be helpful to know. At least to check installation was complete on cygwin part.

Comment: it seems something wrong with cygwin installation. can I use `Gow` instead: `https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki`?

Comment: Hmm that seems good. I will try it at home tonight. If it works well, I can recommend people with that next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now it worked when I installed 'Gow'; a lightweight version with a small file size about 18 MB compared to the heavy Cygwin over 100 MB as described by this source: https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki. Very easy to install. Just make sure that the binary path to environmental variables is right there (it was automatically added after installation didn't need to add it manually). Restart Emacs. No need to restart machine. Cygwin installation was not user-friendly at all.

Select files to run grep on by `C-SPC` or all `M-a`:

[image]

Press `C-s` for grep search and you get online matching. Just great!
[image]

**Update**
After installing Gow it worked well, but after restarting my machine and for some reason Emacs could not pick up `Gow` right. But adding these two lines of code to my `init.el` solved that:

```
(setq exec-path (add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Program Files/Gow/bin"))
(setenv "PATH" (concat "C:\\Program Files\\Gow\\bin;" (getenv "PATH")))
```

Now when I run `getenv PATH` from eshell, the binary path to Gow shows first. This might be important to get things set.

Comment: Congratulation. So, did `helm-projectile-grep` work as well?

Comment: @TuDo, Thanks! I am really glad that you introduced me to it. Now I am experiencing E-MAX rather than just Emacs. BTW, grep version from eshell reads: `GNU grep 2.5.4`

Comment: @TuDo, when I mark all files `M-a` I wish there was a way to change that and demark them by another `M-a`, like what `C-SPC` does. May be a feature request.

Comment: Press `M-a` again, and they will be unmarked. That command is for toggling.

Comment: Unfortunately, `M-a` does not toggle with me as `C-SPC`!

Comment: Here another useful feature of `helm-projectile-grep` and `helm-do-grep`: you can save the grep results in a buffer. With [wgrep](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-wgrep) installed, you can write on that buffer with `C-c C-p`, make some changes on each line, sync with `C-c C-e` and see changes in relevant places; cancel with `C-c C-k` if you don't want to apply any change. Combine with [iedit](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Iedit), and you can perform mass query and replace interactively. Both packages can be installed from MELPA.

Comment: it is bound to backward-sentence for paragraphs.el. May be thats why. I think I need to rebound, but what command?

Comment: Ops sorry. It's `M-m` for toggling the marks. Btw, you can also use `helm-projectile-grep` to grep from project root, unless you want to grep in a specific directory. But, if you want to grep a specific directory, use `helm-projectile-find-dir` and press `C-s` on a dir/multiple marked dirs to grep that directory; `C-u C-s` to recursively grep everything in that directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20110/discussion-between-doctorate-and-tu-do).

Comment: No `M-a` is fine you don't need to rebind. When entering Helm mode, the relevant key bindings for Helm will be replaced. Exiting Helm, you get back normal key bindings.

Comment: You don't need to enter the slash in your pattern. Simply type "phd.tex" and it will give exact results that has `php` and `.tex` in it.

Comment: @TuDo thanks for the tip! `phd`<onespace>`\.tex` will do either.

Comment: `helm-projectile-grep` is now working in Windows again. It was broken because a change made to fix for Mac OS X. I guess that the reason why you was using `helm-ff-do-grep` in `helm-find-files`.