# Searching for multi-line text in many files

Tags: isearch

I have a phrase, e.g. *This is an example phrase*, and a collection of text files (`coll.d/a.txt`, `coll.d/b.txt`, etc.), and I'm looking for the former in the latter.

The thing is, maybe my pattern is splitted over several lines of text, so plain grep [isn't so simple](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204139/24170).
I like the way <kbd>C-s</kbd> deals with spaces, case, the kill-ring, and so on, and look for such behaviour.

So how can I search many files with it ?

---

<sub>Certainly an answer is burried somewhere in [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Search.html) or [manuals](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CategorySearchAndReplace) but `rgrep`, `find`, `replace`, `regexp`, and `occur` somewhat complicate the search, without even mentionning all things `dired`.</sub>

Comment: Over 10k files in a remote dired buffer, (`* t` takes a while and) `M-s a C-s` freezes forever before even asking for a search string. I guess that's asking too much, but I wonder if there's another way (or why it should take so much ressources).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Mark the files in Dired (`* t` to mark all).
2. Use `M-s a C-s` to search them. For regexp search, use `M-s a C-M-s`.

See the Emacs manual, nodes [Misc Dired Features](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-Dired-Features.html) and [Marks vs Flags](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Marks-vs-Flags.html).

If you need to search in a hierarchy of directories (i.e., recursively), use [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) and prefix key **`M-+`** (i.e., `M-+ M-s a C-s` or `M-+ M-s a C-M-s`).

(You can also search a set of files anywhere the same way. Create a [Dired buffer of arbitrary files](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/6008/105), from anywhere, and use the same search keys.)