# lose reftex-isearch-minor-mode after refresh

Tags: auctex, minor-mode, isearch, reftex-mode

I want to activate `reftex-isearch-minor-mode` and tried the solution in [this post offered by giordano](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/6006/17511),

```
(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook (lambda () (reftex-isearch-minor-mode))) ; for AUCTeX
```

it works when I first open `.tex` file on emacs, but the minor mode will be lost, and the multi-search mode becomes the usual search mode after either <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> or revert buffer.

How can I keep the `reftex-isearch-minor-mode` when I do the refreshing? Many thanks!

My AUCTeX version is 11.90.2, emacs version is 24.5.2

Comment: What happens if you pass a positive argument to `reftex-isearch-minor-mode`?  I.e., `(add-hook 'TeX-mode-hook (lambda () (reftex-isearch-minor-mode 1)))`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati sadly, no... and now I cannot even get it to work after restart. Except when I do manually `M-x reftex-isearch-minor-mode RET`. I probably should not be asking this, but what is the minimum amount of code in the `.emacs` to make it work? I have tried this line alone, and with `(setq TeX-parse-self t)`, and a lot other variants...

Comment: @ArashEsbati, I just found that `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (reftex-isearch-minor-mode)))` does work (with TeX-LaTeX), at least so far... but I have to put it before `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)`. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

---

Here is the way to go:

```lisp
(defun mylatexhook nil
   (turn-on-reftex)
   (add-hook 'reftex-mode-hook 
      (lambda nil (reftex-isearch-minor-mode 1))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'mylatexhook)
```

It has to be done in two steps, that was the mystery to be solved!

HTH, O.

Answer (score 0):

Hello some years afterwards,

For those who are still searching for an answer like me ... I decided to go for the radical line of code

---

```lisp
(eval-after-load "reftex" (setq reftex-isearch-minor-mode t))
```

---

in my `.emacs` file.

reftex autoloads lots of things ... This way, we are sure that we overwrite the initial value (that is `nil` in `reftex.el`).